# If char *name = "Emma", why is &name not the same as &name[0]?

Tags: c++, c, cs50

I've been following CS50 and I'm pretty sure I keep hearing that a pointer is just an address

And that the address of an array is just the address of the first item in that array

But when I run the following code:

```
// we can also just create strings we need by using char * like this
char *name = "Emma 123";
char *another_string = "4";
printf("This is the string we get from name: %s\n", name);

// Print the value of the pointer pointing to name
printf("This is the pointer we get from name: %p\n", name);

// Now print out the address of the first letter in Emmas name
printf("This is the pointer we get by resolving &name: %p\n", &name);
printf("This is the pointer we get by resolving &name[0]: %p\n", &name[0]);
printf("Hmmmm. There is something different between &name and &name[0]. Somehow, I thought they should be the same ")
```

I get this as the output:

```
This is the string we get from name: Emma 123
This is the pointer we get from name: 0x4007ad
This is the pointer we get by resolving &name: 0x7ffd2d7d5468
This is the pointer we get by resolving &name[0]: 0x4007ad
```

I've been reading background articles but somehow, I can't seem to grasp why &name and &name[0] aren't the same

edit: I removed the c++ tag as I had incorrectly assumed these elements were common to c and c++
edit: I then added it back as it appears someone else did the same then decided it was a bad idea. Trying not to offend people

Comment: `char *name = "Emma 123";` is not valid in C++, while address of pointer is quite different from address of first element of array it points to...

Comment: Cor C++? Pick one.

Comment: `name` is not an array. It is a pointer.

Comment: please only tag the language you are actually using. C and C++ are different languages and your code is one example where C and C++ differ.

Comment: @user7860670 Since what you're saying is true, I removed the C++ tag.

Comment: @klutt note that your tag removal rendered two and a half c++ answers obsolete. I do agree with the updated tagging, though not sure how to proceed in such case. Anyhow, would be nice to inform the answers, because they were at least half correct before ;)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes, I know and that made me hesitate. But as my defense I say that those answers were prematurely posted. :)

Comment: @klutt I once got complaint for tag removal for exactly this reason (to making answers not matching potentially).

Comment: @Scheff There are quite a lot of things that does not have 100% consensus around here.

Comment: @klutt Concerning this, I was advised to read the tag doc. (I look whether I can find this specific passage again...) Found it: _Be careful about re-tagging questions once there are answers posted, particularly if there are already both C and C++ answers posted. In such cases, the tags should be left alone, since changing them would make posted answers invalid._ (in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info)

Comment: @Scheff In this particular case, it's no question about it, since the first line would not even compile on a C++ compiler. But OP askes about why the output looks the way it does. Therefore, the code compiles, and that proves it's a C compiler and not a C++ compiler. (Or a non-conforming C++ compiler)

Comment: @Scheff Also, a neat and common solution to that is to edit the answer and write something like "Question was originally tagged C++"

Comment: @klutt `and that proves it's a C compiler and not a C++ compiler` Succesfully compiling non-conforming code doesn't make a compiler non-conforming. Compiler is only required to diagnose ill-formed programs (except for certain ill-formed programs where that requirement is explicitly relaxed). Furthermore, in c++03 and older standards, the program is well-formed.

Comment: @klutt Many compilers (clang, gcc) accepts the non-conformant line with a `-Wwritable-strings` warning (_ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to `char *`_), and we commonly see this mistake made in C++-tagged questions also. The `printf` would be a stronger indicator, but this is also commonly abused in older textbooks "on C++" (which for some reasons many novices tend to get their hands on).

Comment: You're right. I just checked it. I just got a warning and not an error. Sorry guys, I made a mistake here.

Comment: I guess I'm not the only one who was to trigger happy ;)

Comment: This is a c question - Seems like a wrongly assumed these elements were the same in c and c++. That will definitely have been adding to my confusion as I read around the subject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char *name = "Emma 123";`

`name` stores the address of first element ('E').

`&name` is the address of `name`. It is a pointer to pointer.

`&name[0] = &(*(name+0)) = (address of first element) = name`

Answer (score 1):

`&name` is the memory location of the pointer to your array.

`&name[0]`  is the memory location of the first char in your array.

Comment: just a note :) `name` is also a memory location of the first char in your array

Answer (score 1):

**For C++** (I don't know C, but I do know that this code is different whether it is C or C++):

String literals are constant. It should be

```
const char *name = "Emma 123";
```

That aside, `name` is already the pointer to the first element in the array. You get expected output with:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){

    const char* name = "Emma";
    std::cout << static_cast<const void*>(name) <<"\n";
    std::cout << static_cast<const void*>(&name[0]) << "\n";

}
```

Possible output:

```
0x402005
0x402005
```

The static cast is needed to bybass the `ostream::operator<<` for `char*` that prints the string.

`&name` is the address of where `name` is stored, not the address stored in `name`.

Comment: *"String literals are constant"* - In C++ yes, in C no

Comment: @klutt sorry I didnt see the C tag and assumed it is C++ :/

Comment: Op has unfortunately tagged both languages

Comment: @klutt your tag removal rendered my answer obsolete. Though, no worries, it was OPs and my fault. I agree with the tagging.

Comment: @klutt seems the issue was resolved. Anyhow, now I am curious: "In C++ yes, in C no" are they really not constant in C? Or is it just "ok" to write `char *name = "Emma 123";` as long as you are not attempting to modify it? (as it was in C++, if I remember correctly)

Comment: It's completely ok in both languages to write `const char *s = "xxx"`, since it's always ok to make a pointer to const point to a non-const object. But in C++, a string literal has the type `const char[]` but in C it's just `char[]`. However, it's UB to modify string literals, so you should always treat them as read only anyway.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the reason that string literals are const in C++ is because compilers can coalesce identical strings.  Lots of C compilers also allow this, but the developer need to be careful with compiler flags if mutating the C string literal.  In addition, because of the C++ rule, the compiler/linker may place string literals into a read-only segment (for platforms that support a read-only segment).

Comment: @klutt thanks, I reread the docs, and if I got it correctly, in C++ string literals always have been `const char [N]` and the conversion to `char *` was only for compatibility with C, and has been dropped in C++11.

Comment: @Eljay effectively they are `const`, no doubt (both in C and C++). My confusion was about what changed with respect to assigning them to a non const `char*`. In the meantime I found the answer (see last comment)

Comment: @Eljay My guess is that they are const in C++ because that's the only reasonable thing to do if it's UB to modify them, but they could not change this in C due to backwards compability.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: as this is a multi-tagged C/C++ question: this answer applies to C++**

---

From [Member access operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access):

> Built-in subscript operator provides access to an object pointed-to by the pointer or array operand. [...]
>
> The built-in subscript expression `E1[E2]` **is exactly identical to the expression** `*(E1 + E2)` [except evaluation order (since C++17)], that is, the pointer operand (which may be a result of array-to-pointer conversion, and which must point to an element of some array or one past the end) is adjusted to point to another element of the same array, following the rules of pointer arithmetics, **and is then dereferenced**.

meaning `&name[0]`, which is `&(name[0])` is equivalent to `&(*name)`.

Also note that string literals should be constants (and your compiler should either reject your program, or emit a warning about non-conformant C++). Corrected example (C++, not C):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const char * name = "Emma 123";
    std::cout << name << "\n"; // Emma 123
    std::cout << &name << "\n"; // 0x7ffd2d7d5468
    std::cout << &(*name) << "\n"; // Emma 123
    std::cout << &(name[0]) << "\n"; // Emma 123
}
```

As `name` is a pointer, `&name`, which takes the address of the pointer, is a pointer to a pointer.

```
#include <type_traits>

const char * name = "Emma 123";
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(&name), const char **>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(&(*name)), const char *>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(&(name[0])), const char *>);
```

Now, whilst [`std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) has a overload with a function parameter `const void *`, it has [a non-member overload or for `const char*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2)

> Character and character string arguments (e.g., of type `char` or `const char*`) are handled by the non-member overloads of `operator<<.`

Thus, for `const char*` arguments, the non-member overloads will chosen, which will print the characters from the character array whose first element is pointed to by the `const char*` pointer.

For `const char**`, however, the member `const void*` will be chosen:

```
std::cout << &name << "\n"; // 0x7ffd2d7d5468
std::cout << static_cast<const void*>(&name) << "\n"; // 0x7ffd2d7d5468
```

Comment: that doesnt explain why printing `&name` is not the desired output, or maybe it does, only OP knows what it takes to debunk their misunderstanding ;)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Expanded/clarified to help out the debunking!

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies to both C and C++, with the exception of the paragraph that says "in C++".

> why is &name not the same as &name[0]?

Because the address where the pointer is stored is separate from the address where the pointer points to, which is where the array is.

> And that the address of an array is just the address of the first item in that array

You seem to be conflating arrays and pointers. An array is not a pointer and pointer is not an array. The quoted sentence is about arrays and it doesn't apply to pointers.

---

> ```
> char *name = "Emma 123";
> ```

This is ill-formed in C++ (since C++11). String literal is not convertible to a pointer to non-const char. To fix this, use `const char*`.

---

> ```
> printf("This is the pointer we get from name: %p\n", &name);
> printf("This is the pointer we get by resolving &name: %p\n", &name);
> ```

The behaviour of this program is undefined. You **must** pass arguments of correct type, and the correct type for `%p` is `void*` while you passed `char*` and `char**`. A corrected example:

```
const void* v_name = name;
void* v_name_a = &name;
printf("This is the pointer we get from name: %p\n", v_name);
printf("This is the pointer we get by resolving &name: %p\n", &v_name_a);
```

Comment: I would've given this a +1 if you drop the last one. All pointers can be implicitly cast to `void*` when required - that `name` is a `char*` makes no difference. [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Pointer_conversions)

Comment: @iBug `All pointers can be implicitly cast to void*` casts are never implicit :) You probably mean implicit conversion. You are making assumptions about conversions that don't apply to varargs. A cast is required here.

Comment: Varargs doesn't make any difference here - all pointers have an equal size and are stored and processed equally w.r.t. storage and memory layout. Implicit conversion still applies here.

Comment: @iBug `all pointers have an equal size` That assumption is not guaranteed by the  C nor C++ standard, and isn't true for all language implementations.

Comment: I may have misremembered something, but `void*` and `char*` must have identical representations (6.2.5:28)

Comment: @iBug Consequently, I wouldn't expect anything other than the desired behaviour. Regardless, the C standard says `The argument shall be a pointer to void.` and `If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined. ` I see no reason to not conform to the specification given how small the difference is.

Comment: `void* v_name = name;` is ill-formed if `name` is `const char *`